# warranty expired?

Tags: mysql, date

I have two values, an InvoiceDate (format: YYYY-MM-DD) and an WarrantyPeriod (format : nn) (number of years for warranty)

An easy Query to select the items where warranty has expired?

I tried with this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(item_invoice_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) AS ux_id,
        (item_warranty_period * 365 * 86400) AS ux_wp
    FROM
        items
    WHERE
        items.item_warranty_period > 0
    AND
        items.item_invoice_date != '0000-00-00'
) wd
,items
WHERE
items.item_warranty_period > 0
AND
items.item_invoice_date != '0000-00-00'
AND
wd.ux_id - wd.ux_wp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
GROUP BY
items.item_id
```

But seems not to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  items
WHERE
  NOW() > (invoice_date + INTERVAL warranty_period YEAR)
```

Comment: But of course.. Just thought of it after shutting down the PC - like a "douh.." ;-)

Comment: @osomanden, happens to everybody :P I simply assumed there would be some form of adding dates, and looked up the docs (at dev.mysql.com, keep that link handy!) for the specific way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get really what you want with your query, but are you Looking for this?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ADDDATE(InvoiceDate, INTERVAL WarrantyPeriod YEAR) < NOW()`

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html